# Need an approach to get the color codes from a css file

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I need an approach to find out the colors available in a CSS file and export it to an excel file

```
.download-hero, .download-version-toggle, a.is-version {
    color: #eaf5e9;
    background: #026e00
}
```

So I need to search if there is a color element. If so then I need to export it to an excel sheet like below.

```
.download-hero                   #eaf5e9      
.download-version-toggle         #eaf5e9  
a.is-version                     #eaf5e9
```

Comment: Hi, is this for a browser with css already loaded, or for an offline node script?

Comment: var color = $(".class").css( "background-color" ); something like this

Comment: Are you missing comma's between the css selectors? As currently written, the color is only applied to `a.is-version` if nested inside `.download-hero` and `.download-version-toggle`

Comment: Hi @georg. It is an Offline node script. I just have the CSS file with me .

Comment: For an offline script, look around on npmjs.com for a "css parser". I'm sure there are plenty of them. Feed your css to the parser, and once you get a js structure back, fetch the data you need from it. Do NOT attempt to do that with regexes et al.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @georg that you shouldn't be doing this yourself due to complexity of parsing CSS. However, if the CSS you are parsing is relatively simple and predictable you could use regex to achieve it.

This example could be used for basic CSS (won't support media queries for example):

```js
const css = `.download-hero, .download-version-toggle, a.is-version {
    color: #eaf5e9;
    background: #026e00
}

a > b {
    background-color: #026e00
    color: black;
}`;

const selectorExp = /\s*([^{]+?)\s*\{\s*([^}]+?)\s*\}/g;
const colorExp = /(^|[\s;])color\s*:\s*([^;]+)/i;

let selectorMatch;
let colors = [];

while (selectorMatch = selectorExp.exec(css)) {
  const [match, selectors, rules] = selectorMatch;
  const colorMatch = colorExp.exec(rules);

  if (colorMatch) {
    colors = colors.concat(selectors.split(/\s*,\s*/g).map(s => ({
      selector: s,
      color: colorMatch[2],
    })));
  }
}

console.log(colors);
```